# jQuery each function not working solution

Tags: jquery, each

When I click the yesBtn or noBtn I would like the corresponding divs in my html with a display of 'none' to become block. In other words, when i click the yesBtn i would like  to have a style of display: block, however, if noBtn is clicked i'd like div with an id="no-section" to have a display style of "block". I thought the each() function would be a solution to my issue. however, when i click yesBtn or noBtn the yes-section's display style becomes "block". The chrome console outputs [Object Object]. Any help with along with explanation highly welcome.

```
const yesBtn = $('#yes-btn'),
        noBtn = $('#no-btn'),
        yesSection = $('#yes-section'),
        noSection = $('#no-section');

$([yesBtn, noBtn]).each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            console.log($(this) + ' was just clicked');
            $([yesSection, noSection]).each(function () {
                $(this).css('display', 'block');
            });
            $(this).parent().slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Updated Code: In Google Chrome I'm now seeing the proper index for noBtn and yesBtn. However, they're both continuing to correspond to div yes-section and changing the display to block.

```
$.each(array, (index, value) => {
        value.on('click', function () {
            console.log(index);
            $.each([yesSection, noSection], (index, value) => {
                value.css('display', 'block');
            });
            value.parent().slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: The iteration shouldn't be causing you a problem, however, the iteration is also entirely redundant. .click() and methods like it (all setters, event handlers, event triggers, and traversal methods) will implicitly iterate over a collection of elements on it's own.

Comment: `$(this)` is a jQuery object, so when you try to log it directly to console it is expected to see `[Object Object]`.

Comment: well, only because it was concatenated with a string with `+`. If you instead used a comma, it would have actually logged the object rather than a string representation of it.

Comment: In Google Chrome I'm now seeing the proper index for noBtn and yesBtn. However, they're both continuing to correspond to div yes-section and changing the display to block. please see updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's see what happens when your code gets executed :

- `console.log($(this) + ' was just clicked')`: here we have an `object` (`$(this)`) concatenated with a `string`, this normally can't happen :

  - the `JavaScript` engine tries to convert (represent would be better) the `object` (`$(this)` in our case) so it calls the `toString` method on that `object`.
  - any `object` has the `toString` method by default due to `prototype`'s chain as any `JavaScript` `object` *inherits* from the base `Object`, it returns a string representation of the actual `object` (`$(this)` in our case).
  - as `jQuery` doesn't override the default `toString` method, the default response (which is `[object Object]`) is returned.
  - now we have the `object` string representation `[object Object]` concatenated with `was just clicked`, that's why you get `[object Object] was just clicked`.
  - if you want to log the `$(this)` object you may pass it to `console.log` without any concatenations with other strings.
- `$(this).css('display', 'block')`: in the loop that iterates over `yesSection` and `noSection`, `$(this)` gets each one of them accordingly and applies to them a `display: block` rule thus regardless of which `button` was pressed **both** the `section`s appear.

So, here's a demo on how to show specific `section` according to the `button` that was pressed :

- in fact you don't need to loop through the `section`s.
- in the click listener check which button was pressed :

  - if `yesBtn` was pressed, show `yesSection` and hide `noSection`.
  - otherwise, show `noSection` and hide `yesSection`.
  - also, no need to hard-code the `display` rule just call `jQuery`'s `show()` and `hide` methods.

Here's a demo :

```js
const yesBtn = $("#yes-btn"),
  noBtn = $("#no-btn"),
  yesSection = $("#yes-section"),
  noSection = $("#no-section");

$([yesBtn, noBtn]).each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    /** check if "yesBtn" was pressed using "is" method **/
    if ($(this).is(yesBtn)) {
      yesSection.show();
      noSection.hide();
    } else {
      noSection.show();
      yesSection.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="yes-btn">yes</button>
<button id="no-btn">no</button>
<div id="yes-section" style="display: none;">yes section</div>
<div id="no-section" style="display: none;">no section</div>
```

> Learn more about [`is`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) method.

Comment: Thanks. Will this still work if i replaced each() with $.each() ?

Comment: @user3574939 yes `$.each($([yesBtn, noBtn]), function() {..}`.

Answer (score -4):

The each method need an array to work.
You can try like this :

```
const yesBtn = $('#yes-btn'),
    noBtn = $('#no-btn'),
    yesSection = $('#yes-section'),
    noSection = $('#no-section');
var array = [yesBtn,noBtn];

array.each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        console.log($(this) + ' was just clicked');
        $([yesSection, noSection]).each(function () {
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
        });
        $(this).parent().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Arrays don't have an `each` method.

Comment: as @KevinB said arrays don't have `each` method you may use `$.each(array, (index, value) => {...})`.